# Where are std::list elements allocated?

Tags: c++, qt, std, qtcore, stdlist

I am playing around with std::list to understand how it stores elements. I have written the following code to check where the elements are allocated.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <list>

class Dummy
{
public:
    Dummy(int i) : _i(i){qDebug() << _i << " created";}
    Dummy(const Dummy& copy) : _i(copy._i) {qDebug() << _i << " copied";}
    ~Dummy() {qDebug() << _i << " destructed";}

    void* operator new (std::size_t size)
    {
        qDebug() << "Object newed";
        return ::operator new(size);
    }

    void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr)
    {
        qDebug() << "Object newed 2";
        return ::operator new(size, ptr);
    }

    void* operator new (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value)
    {
        qDebug() << "Object newed 3";
        return ::operator new(size, nothrow_value);
    }

    void* operator new[](std::size_t size)
    {
        qDebug() << "Object array newed";
        return ::operator new[](size);
    }

    void* operator new[] (std::size_t size, const std::nothrow_t& nothrow_value)
    {
        qDebug() << "Object array newed 2";
        return ::operator new[](size, nothrow_value);
    }

    void* operator new[] (std::size_t size, void* ptr)
    {
        qDebug() << "Object array newed 3";
        return ::operator new[](size, ptr);
    }

    void operator delete(void* dptr)
    {
        qDebug() << "Object deleted";
        ::operator delete(dptr);
    }

    void operator delete[](void* dptr)
    {
        qDebug() << "Object array deleted";
        ::operator delete[](dptr);
    }

    int _i;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::list<Dummy> lstEntries;
    lstEntries.push_back(Dummy(1));
    lstEntries.push_back(Dummy(2));

    std::list<Dummy> newList;
    lstEntries = newList;

    return 0;
}
```

None of my operator new overrides are getting called when I insert elements into the list. Why is that? Doesn't the list allocate it's elements in the heap? Or have I missed the correct new operator which the list uses to allocate objects?

If I use a QList (Qt) instead of std::list, void* operator new (std::size_t size) gets called. Looks like QList allocates it's elements in heap.

Comment: It is not a Qt question, is it? Your code is wrong anyway: `warning: deleting ‘void*’ is undefined`.

Comment: Standard library containers use an allocator.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator

Comment: I only used Qt tag because I used QList instead of std::list too

Comment: Can you please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Your code is broken, it does not even compile.

Comment: May be you forgot to include all necessary includes? I added my includes here. You can remove constructors and delete operators to make the code a little shorter

Comment: `May be you forgot to include all necessary includes?` -> No, that warning has nothing to do with includes. Also, what do QApplication and QtNetwork have to do with a list or even the whole QtCore module?

Comment: Actually my code doesn't compile without #include <QApplication>. <QtNetwork> is not necessary. I removed it. I too get some warnings but this compiles

Comment: No no no, what I was writing is that why you are even using QApplication for this, especially without launching an event loop or using it for anything, especially with core stuff, why gui, why application, why this? Is it really related to the issue?

Comment: Yes. you are correct. They were their because I wrote this by modifying an existing code that was doing something else. I removed those unnecessary items

Comment: But if you remove that, you also have to remove these unnecessary variables! `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Plus, do not include the whole core module, especially now, not using QList. You could also replace qDebug with std::cout to make it a completely std issue.

Comment: Note that `QList` is a flavor of a dynamic array, while `std::list` is a linked list. They are *very* different data structures, even though there are some overlapping use cases where you could reasonably use either (for example implementing a FIFO).

Comment: I think you're assuming `lstEntries.push_back(Dummy(1));` should call "new Dummy()`.  That's simply not necessarily the case.  Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_%28C%2B%2B%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is that `QList` stores its elements internally in a `void*` pointer, whereas `std::list` will use its allocator for all this disregarding your new operator override.

Comment: Additional info: `void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr)` will be called by QVector. Furthermore, do not get tempted about std::list and QList being the same or even very similar. The former is a linked-list, whereas the latter is not.

Comment: I forgot that there is a thing called allocators. Thanks for pointing that out